# method do not support web service callouts

Tags: apex, unit-test

Help me write test class for a method with http call. While testing i am getting **method do not support web service callouts**

Method:

```
public PageReference sendBulkSMSToLeads(){
    List<Lead> matchingLeadsList = [Select MobilePhone from Lead where Status =:leadStatus and Intake_Month__c =:intakeMonth
                                    and Intake_Year__c =:intakeYear];
    Set<String> uniquePhoneNumberList = new Set<String>();                                
    if(matchingLeadsList != null && matchingLeadsList.size() > 0){
        String commaSeparatedMobileNumbers = '';
        for(Lead lead : matchingLeadsList){

            if(lead.MobilePhone != null && lead.MobilePhone != ''){
                if(!uniquePhoneNumberList.contains(lead.MobilePhone)){
                    uniquePhoneNumberList.add(lead.MobilePhone);
                    commaSeparatedMobileNumbers = commaSeparatedMobileNumbers + ',' + lead.MobilePhone;
                }
            }
        }

        if(commaSeparatedMobileNumbers.length() > 0){
            commaSeparatedMobileNumbers = commaSeparatedMobileNumbers.substring(1, commaSeparatedMobileNumbers.length());
        }

        String payLoad = 'username=myusername&password=mypassword&mobile=' +commaSeparatedMobileNumbers + '&sendername=SPJAIN&message='+message;
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://priority.muzztech.in/sms_api/sendsms.php'); 
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(payLoad);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new  ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Bulk SMS initiated for ' + matchingLeadsList.size() + ' leads');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 

    }else{
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new  ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No matching leads found to send SMS');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

And test method i am writing is:

```
static testMethod void sendBulkSMSToLeadsTest() {
    Test.startTest();
    SMSController ctrl = new SMSController();        
    ctrl.leadStatus = 'Hot';
    ctrl.intakeMonth = 'January';
    ctrl.intakeYear = '2017';
    Lead leadObj = new Lead(LastName='Test', Email='unittest2@gmail.com', MobilePhone='7854945777', Status = 'Hot', LeadSource = 'Chat', Intake_Year__c = '2017', Intake_Month__c = 'January');
    insert leadObj;
    ctrl.sendBulkSMSToLeads();

    Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Thanks for suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

Your test class cannot make a callout to the external service during its run and hence salesforce provides a HttpCalloutMock interface to mimic the test case .

The [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) describes how to implement a mock interface

You will create a fake response using the mock interface like below

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
// Implement this interface method
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
    // and method.
    System.assertEquals('http://priority.muzztech.in/sms_api/sendsms.php', req.getEndpoint());
    System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

    // Create a fake response
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{"foo":"bar"}');//add your fake JSON here
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
   }
 }
```

You can modify your test code as below

```
static testMethod void sendBulkSMSToLeadsTest() {
   Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
  Test.startTest();
  SMSController ctrl = new SMSController();        
  ctrl.leadStatus = 'Hot';
  ctrl.intakeMonth = 'January';
  ctrl.intakeYear = '2017';
  Lead leadObj = new Lead(LastName='Test', Email='unittest2@gmail.com', MobilePhone='7854945777', Status = 'Hot', LeadSource = 'Chat', Intake_Year__c = '2017', Intake_Month__c = 'January');
  insert leadObj;

  ctrl.sendBulkSMSToLeads();
  //Assert the response here
 Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class have web service method which needs the test class to make mock http request and recieve a mock http response, these are fake callouts which are needed to test the code, same as you do to test the normal apex classes to cover the code with fake data. 
You will need to create mock classes for testing and will need to add statement `Test.setMock` in order to use those mock class in your test class.

This salesforce developer article has already described how to test Webservice call outs in detail. `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Mock class to generate fake response and use it in your test class.

Please go through following Trailhead module so that you will get brief idea about how to test web service class.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/module/apex_integration_services?utm_campaign=trailhead&utm_source=sfdc&utm_medium=chatter-success

Thanks,
Nachiket